# Using IntelliJ to compile Java 7, configuration trouble

Tags: intellij-idea, java-7

I am playing with IntelliJ and trying to get it to work with Java 7.

My JDK is set up to point to latest JDK

[image]

Additionally, project is set to use it as well

[image]

Yet, when trying to write Java7 code, it's syntax is not being recognized.

[image]

What am i missing please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the **Project Language Level** to **7.0**. Reload the project when asked:

[image: language level]